# how to postition a text in a lucky wheel

Tags: javafx

i am trying to make a lucky wheel with custom options and weights, when i'm working with all the weights set to 1 every thing seems to be fine, but when i use another weights in one of the options, the text position become messy. i'm using java fx, and the slice is an arc
`double arcMidX = centerX + (WIDTH / 2) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(startAngle + sliceAngle / 2)); // Add the slice angle double arcMidY = centerY + (HEIGHT / 2) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(startAngle + sliceAngle / 2));`
i'm calculating the x and y like this

i honestly don't know how to deal with angles so i tried searching online but i found nothing useful

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and a screenshot of what you are expecting.

Comment: Something like this ?https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hUZU.png

Answer (score 0):

This example will put labels at the middle of every arc. It has line nodes to see what is happening after rotation

**App.java**

```
public class App extends Application {

    private Group group = new Group();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        makeLuckyWheel(24, 300);

        var scene = new Scene(new StackPane(group), 640, 480);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void makeLuckyWheel(double divisions, double radius) {

        double angleStep = 360 / divisions;
        double angleTextOffset = angleStep / 2;

        Group textGroup = new Group();
        double textRadius = radius / 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < divisions; i++) {
            Arc arc = new Arc(0, 0, radius, radius, i * angleStep, angleStep);
            arc.setType(ArcType.ROUND);

            // check and asign different color if i is even or not 
            if (i % 2 != 0) {
                arc.setFill(Color.YELLOWGREEN);
            } else {
                arc.setFill(Color.BLUEVIOLET);

            }

            // x and y values for label coordinates in label translate x and y 
            double xCoordText = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angleTextOffset + (i * angleStep))) * textRadius;
            double yCoordText = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angleTextOffset + (i * angleStep))) * textRadius;

            Label label = new Label("---word " + i);
            label.setPrefHeight(30);

            label.setTranslateX(xCoordText);
            // changing y to align label current height 
            label.setTranslateY(yCoordText - label.getPrefHeight() / 2);

            // line for debugging
            Line line = new Line(0, 0, xCoordText, yCoordText);

            Rotate rotation = new Rotate();
            rotation.setPivotY(label.getPrefHeight() / 2);
            rotation.setAngle(90 - (angleTextOffset + (i * angleStep)));
            label.getTransforms().add(rotation);

            group.getChildren().add(arc);
            textGroup.getChildren().addAll(line, label);

            // setting white background to see y center 
            label.setStyle("-fx-background-color : white ;");

        }
        group.getChildren().add(textGroup);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

Result : 8 arcs

[image: javafx arcs]

result : 24 arcs

[image: javafx arcs]